# Which adapter did I just receive this UDP packet on?

Tags: c#, networking, udp, bootp

I'm trying to write a BOOTP server in c#.

I'm receiving and parsing the BOOTP packet from the client and I need to reply with my server IP address.

The problem is:

- The computer can have multiple network adapters
- The client doesn't yet have an IP address

Is there any way to find out what adapter the UDP packet was received on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possible ways to do this.  Bind a separate socket on each IP on each physical interface, then you'll always know which interface the packet arrived on.  You can also try the IP_RECVIF flag together with the recvmsg socket function, although I don't know if that's supported on Windows.  Steven's has examples in Section 22.2 and 22.6 of Unix Network Programming. You can use the SIOCGIFCONF flag with ioctl to get a list of interfaces on the machine.  There is an example program in UNP section 17.6.  If c# doesn't give you access to these functions but their supported on Windows you could write a simple C program to collect and update the interface / IP info and then use mmap to share a memory region between your C# program and the interface enumerator.